# My Scene changes its color once I add element to it

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, interface

I have a program that's going to be a tic tac toe game GUI and I decided to set the scene color with `LinearGradient` which is far better than plain color but once I add any control to it, it instantly changes its color to the default color of Netbeans GUI "White". I tried to check the size of the label that. might cause kinda stuff but it didn't work. Also, I used `StackPane` and this caused the same thing sadly

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import static javafx.scene.text.Font.font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;

public class GUIProject extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        
      FlowPane top = new FlowPane();
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//-------------------------------Top Scene------------------------------------//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
       
       
     Label title = new Label ("F");
      
      title.setFont(Font.font("Arial Bold", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
     top.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ORANGE, CornerRadii.EMPTY,Insets.EMPTY)));
       title.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
       top.setMinHeight(100);
      title.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       
      
    top.getChildren().add(title);
      
      border.setTop(top);
    
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//-------------------------------Scene Set Up---------------------------------//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

       
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,900,700);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
       
        stage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        
        Stop[] stops = new Stop[] { new Stop(0,Color.rgb(1,255,255)), 
            new Stop(1,Color.BLUE)};
             
    
       LinearGradient g1 = new LinearGradient(0,0,1,0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        scene.setFill(g1);
        stage.show();
        
        }
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up the scene (along with its properties like color) with an empty border first and then after that, adding children (title label) to the border's top region.

Comment: hint: the borderpane fills the complete area of the scene (== covers it). Unrelated: don't hard-code sizing constraints (like min/max/pref)!

Comment: Creating any kind of control will cause the default style sheet to be applied to the contents of the scene, which gives an opaque color to the root node (the border pane in your case). Either make the root transparent, or apply your gradient to the root instead of the scene.